# Is a NAFTA work permit holder in Canada allowed to bring his spouse from another country (such as India)?

Tags: working-visas

If a US citizen is working under a NAFTA work permit in Canada, can he apply for his spouse (who is a citizen of another country such as India) to join him in Canada?

Comment: I'm quite certain that the answer is yes, but I can't find anything unambiguous on the Canadian government's web site to confirm it.